# Using multiple Chromecast to display same content for unattended TV

Tags: chromecast, television

We have a number of TVs where we want to display dynamic content. This is very similar to the built in Chromecast application that displays photos and art from Google, the major difference is that we have a mixture of photos and videos, and want to display for instance a whole video clip, then a few photos for 30 sec. each, then another video, then more photos, and finally when all is done, cycle through the whole thing again. We want to do the setup once for each Chromecast/TV, then let it run for days or even weeks.

One option could be a web server displaying the whole sequence repetitively on a specific web page url, and then have the Chromecast display its assigned web page. I looked at the development docs. and I suspect that I will need to develop a Chrome Sender application and use the standard receiver application on the Chromecast. It is not clear for me if the sender (Chrome) needs to run all the time, or once the setup is done, the Chromecast knows which url to display and can then be left alone for days.

We hope to replace dedicated servers and software that connect to the various TVs, and the Chromecast offering customization could be a very inexpensive solution.

Maybe this does not make sense, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender can be a chrome sender or a native app on an Android or iOS device; as for the receiver, you would need to write a custom receiver; that receiver, which is basically an HTML5 page, can receive the whole schedule (urls, etc) at the very beginning, or it can fetch the schedule dynamically from a certain server, etc. Once the receiver starts, your sender doesn't need to stay connected but if for whatever reason your chromecast is rebooted, or loses connectivity, etc, your sender would need to start your application on the chromecast again; there is no magical way for chromecast to start your app automatically.

Comment: Does the Sender knows that the Received is not working (reboot, loss of connectivity, etc.) so that it can restart it automatically?